# EF Core Generic Context.Find for CRUD (Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete) Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, crud

Consider the following where a controller is generic<T, U> where T : DbContext where U : class, new()

**Note:** This is for scenarios when you have many tables, let's say 25+ even as high as 100+ in some existing databases that you're scaffolding, and you want to have one administrative CRUD view on the backend for listing/adding/updating/deleting records the same for each table, which doesn't need updating as the database schema in the models of the DbContext changes when running tooling like Scaffold-DbContext.

```
    [Route("Get/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
        var entityType = Context.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(x => x.ClrType.Name == typeof(U).Name).FirstOrDefault();
        var keyProperty = entityType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties.ToArray()[0];
        var key = Convert.ChangeType(id, keyProperty.PropertyInfo.PropertyType);
        var result = Context.Find(typeof(U), new object[] { key });
        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

How could you make this generically support multiple fields in a primary key if needed? Is there a cleaner way to do the above?

**Update**, changed ChangeType to TypeDescriptor, added multiple keys to Find:

```
    [Route("Get/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
        string[] keysStr = id.Split(',');
        var entityType = Context.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(x => x.ClrType.Name == typeof(U).Name).FirstOrDefault();
        var keyProperties = entityType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties.ToArray();
        List<dynamic> keys = new List<object>();
        if (keysStr.Length != keyProperties.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Keys must be comma-separated and must be of the same number as the number of keys in the table.");
        }
        for(int i=0;i<keyProperties.Length;i++)
        {
            //var key = Convert.ChangeType(id, keyProperty.PropertyInfo.PropertyType);
            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(keyProperties[i].PropertyInfo.PropertyType);
            var key = converter.ConvertFromString(id);
            keys.Add(key);
        }
        var result = Context.Find(typeof(U), keys.ToArray());
        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

Using string.Split(',') to separate multiple key fields in the Route. Better method?

Comment: How about not doing this generic magic? `Context.Thingamabobs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id)` reads better.

Comment: @Gebb: That's what you do for a single view, but imagine you've got some arbitrarily large number of tables let's say 30+ in a DbContext and you want to provide administrative CRUD views for all of those tables with an interface to list/add/update/delete records that your moderators and administrators would use on the backend, you'll need generics for that. You don't want to strongly type the same essential view. Topic heading says "EF Core Generic Context.Find" I'll update to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although it seems doable, I would advise against this approach.
> Especially problematic are the "C" and "U" of CRUD: how are you going
> to check class invaliants? E.g. the user may submit a Birthday in the
> future or a StartDate after EndDate, and you won't be able to prevent
> that, or at least it will be tricky, especially with complex
> preconditions like "a parent entity in state S must not have more than
> N children".
> If you want to do it anyway, consider letting the client specify the entity type.

It's a good question about C#-based validation checking against invalid entries that an RDBMS usually wouldn't check, such as a Birthday in the future, as well as the others.

Since Scaffold-DbContext creates partial classes for Models and DbContexts, one way is to create a partial for the context in a separate location so as not to be overridden by tooling changes, or you could subclass and implement an interface that you could use for pre-validation.

Here's a simple one:

```
public interface IPrevalidateModel
{
    ValidationResult Validate(Type t, object value);
}

public class ValidationResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class ToDoContext : Models.ToDoApp.ToDoAppDbContext, IPrevalidateModel
{
    public ToDoContext() : base()
    {

    }

    public ToDoContext(DbContextOptions<ToDoAppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public ValidationResult Validate(Type t, object value)
    {
        if (t == typeof(ToDo))
        {
            ToDo validate = (ToDo)value;
            if (validate.Done > validate.Started)
            {
                return new ValidationResult() { Success = false, Message = "Error: Done time is greater than Start time.", Data = value };
            }
        }
        return new ValidationResult() { Success = true, Message = "OK" };
    }
}
```

That one subclasses a context for a simple ToDo app and provides an interface for pre-validation. I've been thinking that another use could be per-table role authorization checking for the different CRUD operations within the context/connection.

Now let's get back to the controller logic, I make a proxy Model class for the logic as a go-between of the Controller and Models, so it's not affected by scaffolding-tooling as well as alleviates clogging of logic in the Controller.

This needs a bit of clean-up, but gives you most of the major goodies you'd want:

```
public class ContextCRUD<T> where T : DbContext, IPrevalidateModel
{
    public class DbUpdateResult
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int SaveChangesResult { get; set; }
        public object Entity { get; set; }
    }

    public class TableInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Type DbSetType { get; set; }
        public Type TableType { get; set; }
        public IEntityType EntityType { get; set; }
    }

    T Context { get; set; }
    IServiceProvider Provider { get; set; }
    public List<TableInfo> TableNames { get; set; }

    public ContextCRUD(T context, IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        Context = context;
        Provider = provider;
        TableNames = ListAllTables();
    }

    List<TableInfo> ListAllTables()
    {
        var entityType = Context.Model.GetEntityTypes().ToArray();
        return entityType.Select(x => new TableInfo() { Name = x.ClrType.Name, TableType = x.ClrType, EntityType = x }).ToList();
    }

    TableInfo GetTable(string table)
    {
        var tableInfo = TableNames.Where(x => x.Name == table).FirstOrDefault();
        if (tableInfo == null)
            throw new Exception($"Table not found '{table}'.");
        return tableInfo;
    }

    public async Task<object> GetAll(string table)
    {
        var tableInfo = GetTable(table);
        var contextSetMethod = Context.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.Name == "Set" && x.ContainsGenericParameters).FirstOrDefault();
        var cMethod = contextSetMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { tableInfo.TableType });
        var results = cMethod.Invoke(Context, null);
        return await Task.FromResult(results);
    }

    public async Task<object> Get(string table, string[] id)
    {
        var tableInfo = GetTable(table);
        var entityType = Context.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(x => x.ClrType.Name == table).FirstOrDefault();
        var keyProperties = entityType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties.ToArray();
        if (id.Length != keyProperties.Length)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Keys must be comma-separated and must be of the same number and the number of keys in the table.");
        }
        object[] keys = id.Zip(keyProperties, (i, p) => { return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(p.PropertyInfo.PropertyType).ConvertFromString(i); }).ToArray();
        var result = Context.Find(entityType.ClrType, keys.ToArray());
        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }

    public async Task<List<dynamic>> GetFields(string table)
    {
        var tableInfo = TableNames.Where(x => x.Name == table).FirstOrDefault();
        if (tableInfo == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid table.");
        }

        var tableType = tableInfo.TableType;

        var props = tableInfo.EntityType.GetProperties();
        List<dynamic> results = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach(var p in props)
        {
            var isGeneric = p.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Length > 0;
            string name = p.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name;
            if (isGeneric)
            {
                name += "[" + p.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0] + "]";
            }
            results.Add(new { Name = p.Name, Type = name });
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(results);
    }

    void UpdateRecordFields(object record, FieldValue[] fields, TableInfo tableInfo)
    {
        var recordProperties = tableInfo.EntityType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var f in fields)
        {
            var recordProperty = recordProperties.Where(x => x.Name == f.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            object value = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(recordProperty.PropertyInfo.PropertyType).ConvertFromString(f.Value);
            recordProperty.PropertyInfo.SetValue(record, value);
        }
    }

    public async Task<DbUpdateResult> Update(string table, string[] id, FieldValue[] fields)
    {
        var tableInfo = GetTable(table);
        var record = await Get(table, id);
        UpdateRecordFields(record, fields, tableInfo);
        var validateResult = Context.Validate(tableInfo.TableType, record);
        if (!validateResult.Success) { 
            return new DbUpdateResult() { Success = false, Message = validateResult.Message, Entity = record, SaveChangesResult = -1 }; 
        };
        Context.Update(record);
        int result = await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return await Task.FromResult(new DbUpdateResult() { Success = (result > 0) ? true : false, Message = "OK", Entity = record, SaveChangesResult = result });
    }

    public async Task<DbUpdateResult> Update(string table, FieldValue[] fields)
    {
        var tableInfo = GetTable(table);
        var record = Activator.CreateInstance(tableInfo.TableType);
        UpdateRecordFields(record, fields, tableInfo);
        var validateResult = Context.Validate(tableInfo.TableType, record);
        if (!validateResult.Success)
        {
            return new DbUpdateResult() { Success = false, Message = validateResult.Message, Entity = record, SaveChangesResult = -1 };
        };
        Context.Update(record);
        int result = await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return await Task.FromResult(new DbUpdateResult() { Success = (result > 0) ? true : false, Message = "OK", Entity = record, SaveChangesResult = result });
    }

    public async Task<DbUpdateResult> Delete(string table, string[] id)
    {
        var tableInfo = GetTable(table);
        var record = await Get(table, id);
        Context.Remove(record);
        int result = await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return await Task.FromResult(new DbUpdateResult() { Success = (result > 0) ? true : false, Message = "OK", Entity = record, SaveChangesResult = result } );
    }
}
```

Then it's on to the actual Controllers:

```
public class ToDoController : GenericController<ToDoContext>
{
    public ToDoController(ToDoContext context, IServiceProvider provider, ILogger<CustomLogger> logger) : base(context, provider, logger)
    {
    }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class GenericController<T> : Controller where T: DbContext, IPrevalidateModel
{
    T Context { get; set; }
    ILogger<CustomLogger> Logger { get; set; }
    ContextCRUD<T> CRUD { get; set; }

    public GenericController(T context, IServiceProvider provider, ILogger<CustomLogger> logger)
    {
        Context = context;
        Logger = logger;
        CRUD = new ContextCRUD<T>(context, provider);
    }

    void LogAction(string action = "")
    {            
        // ... Logger code here ...
    }

    void LogValues(string json)
    {
        ConsoleEx console = new ConsoleEx(); // Note this is a 24-bit ANSI Color Console class I created and am planning to release.
        // ... Logger code here ...
    }

    async Task<IActionResult> RunAction(string actionName, Func<Task<object>> func)
    {
        LogAction(actionName);
        var values = await func();
        LogValues(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values, Formatting.Indented));
        return new JsonResult(values);
    }

    [Route("{table}/")]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetAll(string table)
    {
        return RunAction("GetAll", async () => { return await CRUD.GetAll(table); });
    }

    [Route("{table}/Get/{id}/")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Get(string table, [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CRUDModelCommaBinder))] string [] id)
    {
        return RunAction("Get", async () => { return await CRUD.Get(table, id); });
    }

    [Route("{table}/GetFields/")]
    public Task<IActionResult> GetFields(string table)
    {
        return RunAction("GetFields", async () => { return await CRUD.GetFields(table); });
    }

    [Route("{table}/Add/{fields}/")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Add(string table, [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CRUDModelFieldValueBinder))] FieldValue[] fields)
    {
        return RunAction("GetFields", async () => { return await CRUD.Update(table, fields); });
    }

    [Route("{table}/Update/{id}/{fields}/")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Update(string table, [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CRUDModelCommaBinder))] string [] id, [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CRUDModelFieldValueBinder))] FieldValue[] fields)
    {
        return RunAction("Update", async () => { return await CRUD.Update(table, id, fields); });
    }

    [Route("{table}/Delete/{id}/")]
    public Task<IActionResult> Delete(string table, [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CRUDModelCommaBinder))] string [] id)
    {
        return RunAction("Delete", async () => { return await CRUD.Delete(table, id); });
    }

    public Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return RunAction("Index (Show Table Names)", async () => { return await Task.FromResult(CRUD.TableNames.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name })); });
    }
}
```

> If you want to do it anyway, consider letting the client specify the
> entity type.

Also note that this one is generic T for the DbContext and not <T, U>, I had written a generic T variant earlier but had a lot of reflection logic in ContextCRUD, it's streamlined and a bit cleaner now, although you can get rid of IServiceProvider in ContextCRUD, you might use it though if you want to CreateScope to some other scoped services like accessing other DbContexts or scoped repositories.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

I'll see your external http program and raise you a custom ILogger with a unicode Pacman emoji. On a more serious note though, I can't think of any other pitfalls at the moment unless you can think of anything. Then it's on to making views to consume the JSON api.

Comment: Also, Django has CRUD views and JSON APIs out of the box for scaffolded tables for admin views. This would be a great feature for future .NET Core versions out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems doable, I would advise against this approach.
Especially problematic are the "C" and "U" of CRUD: how are you going to check class invaliants?
E.g. the user may submit a `Birthday` in the future or a `StartDate` after
`EndDate`, and you won't be able to prevent that, or at least it will be tricky,
especially with complex preconditions like "a parent entity in state S must not
have more than N children".

If you want to do it anyway, consider letting the client specify the entity type.

Something like this:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("any")]
public class JackOfAllTradesCOntroller : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyContext _ctx;

    public JackOfAllTradesCOntroller(MyContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        // Add a random entity.
        // Customer configured with:
        // modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(new[] { "Id", "FirstName" });
        _ctx.Customers.Add(
            new Customer() {
                Id = 1,
                FirstName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(1,6),
                LastName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Address = "Addr"
            });
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    private IEntityType GetType(string typeName)
    {
        return _ctx.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .Where(x => x.ClrType.Name == typeName).First();
    }

    [Route("GetAll/{entityType}")]
    public IActionResult GetAll(string entityType)
    {
        IEntityType eType = GetType(entityType);
        MethodInfo set = _ctx.GetType().GetMethod("Set")
            .MakeGenericMethod(eType.ClrType);
        object result = set.Invoke(_ctx, new object[0]);
        return new JsonResult(result);
    }

    [Route("Get/{entityType}")]
    public IActionResult Get(
        string entityType,
        [FromQuery(Name = "id")] string[] id)
    {
        IEntityType eType = GetType(entityType);
        IProperty[] keyProperties = eType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties.ToArray();
        // ... validate id here ...
        object[] keys = id.Zip(
            keyProperties,
            (i, p) => Convert.ChangeType(i, p.PropertyInfo.PropertyType)
            ).ToArray();
        object result = _ctx.Find(eType.ClrType, keys);
        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image: demo]